# show username in url after user logs in asp.net mvc routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, actionfilterattribute

Once user logs in and go to home page, it should add username by default.after login even user try to go mysite.com , it should redirect to mysite.com/username

ex:

mysite.com/home -> mysite.com/username/home

So my question is once user logged in all the pages should have username in the url be default. even if user went to home page, it should deduct user logged in and redirect to home/username.

Comment: So what's the question, and what have you tried to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You have default route in your MVC application like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", userName = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Your default action will be:

```
public ActionResult Index(string username)...
```

Inside this action you will check if username exists. If exists redirect to mysite.com/username/home if not redirect to home page with login:

```
public ActionResult Index(string userName)
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
            {
                return View("Login");
            }

            return Redirect("siteUrlHere" + userName + "/home");
        }
```